# Conseguir botones para compartir en redes sociales y programarlos

Tags: php, javascript, html, redes

Podrian asesorarme sobre donde conseguir este tipo de botones para compartir en redes sociales y como programarlos para compartir diferente contenido..[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Los botones lo puedes hacer tú con html y css, según tu gusto. En cuanto a funcionalidad ... cada Red Social tiene API's que puedes utilizar por ejemplo para compartir contenido: API de Facebook ( https://developers.facebook.com/ ) API de Twitter ( https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs ) ,  etc.

Answer (score 0):

Dependerá de como lo quieres programar....

Puedes empezar mirando:

**FACEBOOK**
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button?locale=es_ES

**TWITTER**
https://publish.twitter.com/#

Comment: y para instagram como seria?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes:

*1) Hacer tu propio boton*

*2) Puedes buscar generadores de botones online*

*3) Puedes googlear además , con algo como `"Boton de facebook para web"`*

```css
input {
border: 2px solid #324a7c;
width: 200px;
height: 50px;
font-family: monospace;
font-size: 25px;
color: white;
background-color: #3B5998;
font-weight: 750;
border-radius: 12px;
position: absolute;
top: 50%; right: 0; left: 0; margin: 0 auto;
}

input:hover {
 transform: scale(1.1);
 transition: all .9s;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Facebook">
```